# how to compare 1 element of a dataframe with all elememts of other dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare each element of child dataframe "df_child" with each element of parent dataframe "df_parent".
I am trying to extract 1 child element and compare with all parent elements by passing them as argument in "similar" function, where i use levenshtein algorithm to give me result in percentage approximation of a child with each parent.

Its giving me following error:

"FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison res_values = method(rvalues)"

Following is my code:

```
import textdistance
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def similar(a,b):
    try:
        result_levenshtein=textdistance.levenshtein.normalized_similarity(a,b)
        print (result_levenshtein)
    except Exception:
        print (Exception)

try:
    df_child = pd.read_excel('parent_child_relationship.xlsx', sheet_name='child')
    df_parent= pd.read_excel('parent_child_relationship.xlsx', sheet_name='parent')
    print (len(df_child.index))
    print (len(df_parent.index))

    for parent in range(len(df_parent.index)):
        parent = df_parent.iloc[:,0]
        #print (parent)
        for child in range(len(df_child.index)):
        child = df_child.iloc[:0]
        #print (child)
        similar(child,parent)

except Exception:
    print (Exception)
```

Comment: It is a warning, not an error.

Comment: ok, but not sure, why am i not able to extract individual values from data frames

Comment: Please check the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

A small modification to the `for` loop. Please check if it works -

```
for parent in range(len(df_parent.index)):
    par = df_parent.iloc[parent:parent+1,0]
    for child in range(len(df_child.index)):
        chi = df_child.iloc[child:child+1, 0] #have assumed here that you want column 0
        similar(chi,par)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the loop that worked :

```
for i in df_parent.index:
    par = df_parent['Column1'][i]#Column1 is the one we added above
    #print("parent "+par)
    for j in df_child.index:
        chi = df_child['Column1'][j]
        #print("child "+chi)
        similar(chi,par)
```